# Any Google Site Search alternatives?

Tags: search, archive, searchable

Could anyone suggest any Google Site Srach alternatives that are not very costy and quite straightforward to implement on a website?

I need this for a searchable archive (PDF and other docs uploaded, that they could be searchable by name).

Google will be ditching their Site Search service end of play this year.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for few options like:

1) Server side coding: You can have code on your server to do a simple search. It would not be as fast as google but still serve the purpose for free.

2) Cloud based: You can go for Amazon or Microsoft cloud based services.

3) Others : Like [swiftype](https://swiftype.com/) or [cludo](https://www.cludo.com/en/) they can cost around 299$ or you can go for [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) which offers many free services.